# Need help with identifying the disease on my mango tree and a possible cure

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, diseases

It started with me seeing dark spots appearing on the leaves of my mango tree, which grows in my apartment. When I looked underneath the leaves I saw something white growing there. Now it has spread to most of the leaves.

Today two of the leaves fell of, probably because of this disease. I have made photos of the tree, the leaves, which fell of, and two detailed macro pictures. But for now I will just add two of the pictures due to not having enough reputation to have more than two links on this page.

I really want my tree to survive so I hope somebody here can help me identifying what disease this is and how to fight it. Preferably in a way I can do it in my apartment.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure it isn't powdery mildew. It rather appears like a [some Spider Mite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_mite) attack. This white stuff is typical of what they will grow beneath the leaves.

Maybe if you look very close on your plant, you will see the biggest insects beneath the live leaves.

Mango tree can be attacked by these insects [ref](http://rachel.golearn.us/modules/en-infonet/export/default$ct$124$crops.html):

> **Mango leafcoating mite (Cisaberoptus kenyae)**
>
> The mango leafcoating mite is tiny (about 0.2 mm), light coloured and cigar shaped. It cannot be seen with the naked eye. The mites leave in groups under a white coating on the upper leaf surface. The white coating can be easily rubbed off by hand. Leaves covered with the white coating tend to turn yellow and drop prematurely. In general, the coating has minimal effect on fruit yield.

I got this on my orchids. I couldn't get rid of them however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to scrape off some of the white stuff and look at it with a (crappy) magnifying tool (60x-100x), but I couldn’t find anything looking like insects or anything moving at all.
What did you see in the pictures suggesting that this could be spider mites and not powdery mildew?

Comment: @eternitysharp, it was the small white rounded things who made me think of them, as well as the Little filaments...

Answer (score 0):

From the two pictures provided, it appears to be powdery mildew.   The contaminated leaves and any fruit should be destroyed and the plant isolated from any other mango trees you may have.  Powdery mildew is host specific so it should not spread to other plants.  The good news is while powdery mildew will stress the host plant, it usually is not fatal.
In addition to removing contaminated leaves, fruit and limbs, the usual control is a fungicide such as coppper or sulphur.  If you are in warm area, you could do the spraying on the apartment patio or deck.  If the plant cannot be moved outside, you could try 'natural' remedies using baking soda or mouthwash.   This article has some ideas under the heading 'Lesser Known Options'
http://www.growingagreenerworld.com/controlling-or-eliminating-powdery-mildew/
Other homemade suggestions at   http://homeguides.sfgate.com/homemade-fungicide-mangoes-86372.html

TL; DR version  - it looks like powdery mildew   Some control suggestions are found at http://www.growingagreenerworld.com/controlling-or-eliminating-powdery-mildew/